# How would I go about serializing multiple file objects into one file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm currently tasked with the difficult problem of figuring out how to efficiently pack an image and some text within a single file. In doing so, I need to make the file relatively small (it shouldn't be much bigger than the size of the image file alone), and the process of accessing and saving the information should be relatively fast.

Now, I have already found one way that works - converting the image to a string using pygame, storing it (and the text I need) within an python object, and then pickling the object. This works fine, but the file ends up being much MUCH larger than the image, since it's not being compressed. So to help with this, I then take the pickled object and compress it using gzip. Now I have another problem - the whole process is just a tad bit too slow, since I'll need to do hundreds of these files at a time, which can take several minutes (it shouldn't take longer than a 1/2 second to load a single file, and this method takes up to 2 seconds per file).

I had an idea to somehow put the two separate files, as they are, into one file like how someone would with a .zip, but without the need to further compress the data. As long as the image remains in it's original, compressed format (in this case, .png), simply storing it's data with some text should theoretically be both fast and wouldn't use much more memory. The problem is, I don't know how I would go about doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look into `tar` or `tar`-like archiving approaches.

Comment: Create a new file and first copy the compressed image file data to it, then concatenate the text immediately following that, and then at the very end tack on a fixed-size block that starts with some sort of unique identifier plus the length of the image file. To read such a file back in, first seek to the end of the file minus the size of the fixed-size block, read in that fixed-size amount of data, verify that the unique id is there and then use the image file-length stored following that read the image file data portion (or skip over it and read the text portion following it).

Comment: why do you care if the new file is bigger? hard drive space is almost free ...

Comment: The files have to be transmitted through a network to several clients.

Comment: It is quite possible that your image format already has some metadata facilities, if your format is jpeg read about EXIF tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex Reynolds idea to use tar archives seems to be a perfect match.